# Get latest post from facebook page (feed)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, app-secret

I'm trying to get the latest facebook post from a facebook page. I'm working with the **facebook php SDK v4** (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/).

I've added the library (php sdk) to composer: `composer require facebook/php-sdk-v4`. My appid / app secret and page id are correct.

```
$config = array();
$config['app_id'] = 'myappid';
$config['app_secret'] = 'myappsecret';

$facebook = new \Facebook\Facebook($config);

$pageid = 'mypageid';

try {

    $pagefeed = $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "/feed");
}
catch(Exception $ex){
    echo $ex->getMessage(); die;
}
```

The problem is I'm getting the error **Call to undefined method Facebook\Facebook::api()**. When I search in other topics online they've used this a lot. But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I can see, `api` isn't a function in any of the Facebook PHP files. Hmm. Have you tried using the `$facebook->get()` function?

Comment: Yes, there's no api method, just get and post methods. Get a look here https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v4-to-v5)

Comment: That is actually v5 of the SDK (see readme on github, they just kept the old URL.) v4 did have an `api` method, but in v5 it was removed. You should always read the official documentation first: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/api/5.0.0

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed) you can get a page feed using the following code:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $fbApp,
  '{access-token}',
  'GET',
  '/{page-id}/feed'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

**Source**: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed

Note that the examples on that page default to the HTTP versions rather than the PHP SDK.

Edit: Added the correct parameters for the FacebookRequest function.

Requires an access token and `$app` instance as shown below.

```
Facebook\FacebookRequest($fbApp, '{access-token}', 'GET', '/{page-id}/feed');
```

The access token can be created using the `getAccessToken()` function as shown below.

```
$access_token =  $facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
```

V4 of the API used a Session system that can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0

Create a Facebook Session variable, and then you can use that `$session` in the original v4 Request method.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{page-id}/feed'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

Comment: And what's the $session variable?

Comment: Sorry. `$session` was apparently removed in v5 of the API. I've updated it to include the latest version info. If you haven't updated to the v5 API from the v4 Github link, you can use the info at the bottom :)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but what's the $fbApp variable? And how can I get the acces token?

Comment: `$fbApp` is the instance of the `FacebookApp` class. If you're using the API, you probably have already created one. If not, I'll add some more info in a bit. To get the access token, you need to use the authentication API. I provided a link, but will detail more about it when I get back to my PC. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's not very clear for me at the moment :)

Comment: Sorry I took so long to reply. With the API, to create the `$fbApp` variable it would be:
`$fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp('{app-id}', '{app-secret}');`
This creates a new FacebookApp instance.

For the AccessToken, it would be:
`$accessToken = new Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken('{access-token}');`